# X is more similar to Y compared to Z

Tags: comparative-constructions

Consider this sentence:

> X is more similar to Y compared to Z

Which of these does this sentence mean?

1. X is more similar to Y and less similar to Z
2. The similarity of X to Y is more than the similarity of Z to Y

If it means the first interpretation, how can I say the sentence to mean the second interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is badly constructed and likely to cause confusion.

To be clear, it needs to read either:

> X is more similar to Y than (X is) to Z

or

> X is more similar to Y than Y is to Z

Comment: Indeed, what I need is something like "X is more similar to Y than Z is to Y". But doesn't any way of expressing it without repeating Y exist?

Comment: @Shayan The formula **Y is more similar to X than to Z** expresses a closer relation between X and Y  than betwen Y and Z

Comment: Thank you, but I want the opposite. Isn't a way? Assume that being similar in my context is not bidirectional and is unidirectional.

Comment: @Shayan I suspect that you want someone with greater mathematical or computational skills than I have.

Comment: Can I use "X is, compared to Z, more similar to Y" to convey what I mean? Doesn't it have the ambiguity?